# Selenium XPATH how can i get text out from table column 4 where text is in table column 2

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML table with some columns and rows.  I am trying to find the text from column 5 and the text from column 3.
The text I would like to find from col 5 is 101 THE BatCave|GOTHAM CITY| and  the text 14 from col 3

To start I first find the text 14 from col 3 with the following XAPTH:

```
//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]//tr//td[3]/div/span[@title="14"]
```

But I don't know how to get the text from column 5 also.
I have tried:

```
//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]//tr//td[3]/div/span[@title="14"] and td[5]//span[contains(text(), "101 THE BatCave|GOTHAM CITY|"])

//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]//tr//td[3]/div/span[@title="14"]/following::td[5]
```

The HTML snippet is:

```
<table id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 17px;">
<colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="GFNQNVHJM" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0" />
        <tr class="GFNQNVHIN" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1"/>
        <tr class="GFNQNVHJM" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2"/>
        <tr class="GFNQNVHJM GFNQNVHAN" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="12"/>
        <td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHLM GFNQNVHBN"/>
        <td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHBN"/>
        <td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHBN"/>
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-319" style="outline-style:none;"/>
        <span title="14" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">14</span>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHBN">
    <td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHBN">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-321" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span title="101 BatCave|GOTHAM CITY|" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">101 THE BatCave|GOTHAM CITY|</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHBN">
        <td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHBN"/>
        <td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHBN"/>
        <td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHBN"/>
        <td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHBN"/>
        <td class="GFNQNVHIM GFNQNVHKM GFNQNVHFN GFNQNVHBN"/>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GFNQNVHIN" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="13"/>
    <tr class="GFNQNVHJM" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="14"/>
</tbody>
```

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: Is in your whole table only these two columns has text??

Comment: The table has different text in other columns. The columns I am interested in is column 3 and 5 which has my expected text 14 and 101 THE BatCave|GOTHAM CITY|

Comment: In my Selenium Python code I can then use an AssertEqual or AssertTrue to verify the text exists in the table

Comment: Ok so do you want combine text from both columns or separate??

Comment: combine both columns

Comment: I am getting closer: //table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]//tr//td[3]/div/span[@title="14"]//following::tr[1]//td[5]/div/span[contains(text(), "101 THE BatCave|GOTHAM CITY|")]

Comment: It's impossible to combine text using xpath but this is possible to get only these two columns element and iterate and then combine it's text in loop.. do you want like this??

Comment: That would be fine then if it has to be in a for loop.  I Could use what alecxe has provided below.  I am trying that now. I can then do an If statement in there to check my expected text

Comment: Yes you can also check my answer which finds only both your desired colum...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to combine both columns together using xpath and get their text combination. You can find only these two columns in the list and then combine their text through loop as below :

```
combineText = ""
columns = driver.find_element_by_id("reporting_view_report_dg_main_body").find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@title = '14'] | .//span[@title = '101 BatCave|GOTHAM CITY|']")
for column in columns:
    combineText += column.text

print(combineText)
```

Comment: Thanks this works for me.  I am able to use this method for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the reliability of this approach in your particular case, but given what provided, you can get both elements by getting `span` elements with `title` attribute:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='reporting_view_report_dg_main_body']//span[@title]")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```